# sshfs: How to mount / to local with normal user ssh-login

Tags: permissions, sshfs

I want to backup my ubuntu-server to local storage with borgbackup in "pull-style" via sshfs as described here: [borgbackup examples](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html) -search page for ("pull" style)- . I configured passwordless ssh-login for a normal user via key and disabled root-login for security reasons. I want to mount servers / to a local dir, so sshfs has to login as a normal user and then do root privilege escalation for mounting operation.

How do I tell sshfs to ask for the server's root-password when doing normal user ssh-login? Is this possible at all?

Comment: I don't see how this makes anything safer then allowing root to use (probably only) sshfs/sftp in the first place. I don't think what you want is possible, nor is it more secure.

Comment: "How do I tell sshfs to ask for the server's root-password when doing normal user ssh-login? Is this possible at all?" NO.

Comment: IMHO it is generally recommended to disable ssh-root-login for security reasons. A possible attacker in my case needs the private ssh-key including it's password, the name of the non-root user to login and the root-password to get root privileges. This seems a lot more secure to me than a direct root-login with pwd and even with a key.